# java get average for all entities in the selected category

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have table of companies and a table of employees that belong to one of these companies in the other table.

I am trying to get the average of the salary of the company for which the user has selected to see the details.

Below in my JSP, i am displaying all of the employees of the chosen company, and right at the bottom, i am trying to display the average salary of all of the employees altogether.

 As you can see, there is a `sum`command that is summing up the salaries for each of the iteration in the for loop and then spitting out the average. 
I would like to do this in my companyDAO or company.java file and just call the method here (which i am doing, but i get zero.).

```
<%@page import="data.Employee"%>
<%@page import="data.Company"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<jsp:useBean id="company" type="data.Company" scope="request"/>

<% List<Employee> employees = company.getEmployees();
   double sum=0.0;
%>
<table border="1">    
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>                        
        <td>Salary</td>             
    </tr>        
    <%
        for(int i=0; i <employees.size(); i++){
            sum += employees.get(i).getSalary();
    %> 
        <tr>      
            <td><%=employees.get(i).getId()%></td>
            <td><%=employees.get(i).getNom()%></td>                
            <td><%=employees.get(i).getSalary()%></td>  
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table> 

//get the average salary of all employees ::: This is returning the average
<p>Average salary of all employees in this company:<%=sum/(double)employees.size()%> </p>
//this is returning zero.       
<p> New average method: <%=company.getAverageSalary()%></p>
```

**companyDAO.java**

```
public static CompanyretrieveById(int id) {         
        EntityManager em = GestionFactory.factory.createEntityManager();
        Company company = em.find(Company.class, id);
        em.close();                 
        return company;
    }
public static List<Company> getAll() {
    EntityManager em = GestionFactory.factory.createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e.company, AVG(e.salary) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.company");

    // each list entry contains a tuple (company, avgSalary)
    List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

    List<Company> companiesList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Object[] entry : results) {
        Company company = (Company) entry[0]; // contains "e.company"
        Double avgSalary = (Double) entry[1]; // contains "AVG(e.salary)"
        company.setAverageSalary(avgSalary);
        companiesList.add(company);
    }

    return companiesList;
}
```

and **company.java**:

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @Transient
    private double averageSalary;

    public void setAverageSalary(double averageSalary) {
        this.averageSalary = averageSalary;
    }

    public double getAverageSalary() {
        return averageSalary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, calculate this value in `company.getEmployees()` and then just add it to your request as an attribute

Comment: You should not really be doing Java code in JSP.  Search for a JSP EL tutorial e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat could you please give an answer so that i can follow what you are saying, thanks

Comment: How about you telling me what you do not understand

Comment: as you can see what i have already tried, and it is returning zero, but if i put it inside the loop, i get the result. so this is what i understand and the rest i don't know unfortunately.